# How can I unite a big string in a single one with no spaces between words?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to know how to unite a big string in one with no white spaces.
I have been trying the following replace(substr((array(i)),0,10),'',NULL)
and Substr((replace(array(i),'',NULL)),0,9); my result needs to be 'Lseries4St'

Both failed

```
DECLARE
p0 varchar2(90) := '';
p1 varchar2(90) := '';
p2 varchar2(90)  := '';
p3 varchar2(90) := 'LUMACHNECRM';
p4 varchar2(90) :='PREPARE';
p5 varchar2(90) :='';
p6 varchar2(90) := '';
p7 varchar2(90) :='';
valor varchar2(20) :='J10';
valor1 varchar2(20) :='TRUE';
p8 varchar2(90) ;
P9 VARCHAR2(90) :='DO';
p10 varchar2(90) :='MACHINECRM';
x varchar2(90);
y varchar2(90);
z varchar2(90);
TYPE array_t IS varray(999) OF VARCHAR2(25);
ARRAY array_t := array_t('Lseries 4 Stone');
BEGIN 
  FOR i IN 1..array.count LOOP
    p8  :='LU'||chr(31)||'MACHINECRM'||chr(30)||'DB_VALUE'||chr(31)||Substr((replace(array(i),'',NULL)),0,10)||chr(30)||
   'CLIENT_VALUE'||chr(31)||array(i)||chr(30)||'USED_DB'||chr(31)||'TRUE'||chr(30);
    LORA1APP.Language_SYS.Set_Language('en'); 
    dbms_output.put_line(p8);
    CUSTOM_FIELD_ENUM_VALUES_API.NEW__( p0 , p1 , p2 , p3 , p4 );
    CUSTOM_FIELD_ENUM_VALUES_API.NEW__( p5 , p6 , p7 , p8 , p9); 

  end loop;
commit;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
REPLACE(array(i), ' ', '');
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7091f2031204978fbe84863302d370eb)
Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=98b0a620472dd18f577baedbaeb6497c) with array(i) inside of the concatenated string.